# QGIS: How to compute mean of raster values without no data?

Tags: qgis, masking

I was able to clip a raster against a vector boundary using `Clip Raster by Mask layer`. I want to compute the mean of the values inside a single raster. I am using `Raster Layer Analysis`. However it seems to add in the computation the no data values set to 0. How to work around this?

I am using QGIS 3.10 on Windows 10.

[image]

The black "outer" values are 0.